# Как определить функцию-обработчик сигнала?

Tags: c, unix, solaris, signal

> Может ли программа определить, какой в данный момент обработчик связан
>   с определённым сигналом?

Как это можно сделать? Известно, что определить обработчик можно, в том числе узнать адрес функции-обработчика.

Comment: В шелле на каждый сигнал, на который нужен независымый обработчик нужно сделать `trap "команда1; команда2;" SIG1 SIG2 SIG3 …`  обычно `команда1` - это функция, которую нужно вызвать.

Comment: если речь о программе, выполняющей роль оболочки, то: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap

Comment: в общем, непонятно, о чём именно речь. потому как в разных языках программирования «ловля» передаваемых процессу сигналов организована по-разному.

Comment: Речь идет о Си. Забыл  добавить тег, но я думал понятно из "адрес функции"(

Comment: Например, [man 2 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)